# Can't Answer on Tor Browser

Tags: bug, answers

It's not possible to answer a question on this site using Tor Browser.

I'm trying to write an answer to [my question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158817/calculating-percent-profit-in-lot-cryptocurrency-forex), but when I click the `Answer Your Question` button, I get a small popup modal that reads

```
Unable to load popup - please try again
```

I'm running Tor Browser (v13.0) with the default settings. Due to my risk model, I cannot test this outside of Tor Browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can visit [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/browser-support) for a list of [browsers supported on the StackExchange Network](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

I am not seeing TOR listed as explicitly supported.